# Set retries on rsync to have fixed time between them

Tags: rsync

I have been having `rsync` try five times to connect. I have been getting exit codes of 11 indicating a file I/O error. When I try using `robocopy` I get an error 59 when I copy a set of files to the same target.

The thing is that `robocopy` succeeds where `rsync` fails, and when I looked in the `robocopy` logs I noticed right after it got the error that it did a retry 30 seconds later. I need to use `rsync` so I am wondering how to set up `rsync` to do a retry for say a network error 30 seconds later. This only happens say 5 times during a transfer of over 200K of files with varying sizes. When I look at the rsync logs immediately after code 11 it immediately requests the list of files from the source to get and it exits with that same exit code of 11 indicating to me it failed.

Command-line

```
rsync -rtlzv -e "ssh -i c:/RsyncKeys/wa-ecy-gov-test-rsync-key -o ConnectTimeout=140 -o ConnectionAttempts=18" --quiet --stats --exclude-from='rsyncfilter.txt' --force --delete cran-rsync@cran.r-project.org: //sdceco/Apps/RSTUDIO/RpackagesNew  --timeout=320 --log-file=c:/rsynclogs/rsync11-05-2020.log
```

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Would the I/O error be an open file.?

Comment: For those reading this question after the event, it turns out [the underlying issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618230/set-retries-on-rsync-to-have-fixed-time-between-them#comment1157751_618231) is a Windows network share failing the destination write

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is similar to this

```
while :
do
    rsync … && break
    sleep 60
done
```

The `rsync` tool exits with status 0 (success) when it completes successfully, which breaks out of the loop. Otherwise, there's a 60 second pause and the loop restarts. In my own implementation of this I tend to use a longer delay and also a counter to exit the loop after `k` tries:

```
ss=127 k=4
while [[ $((k--)) -gt 0 ]]
do
    rsync … && ss=0 && break
    ss=$?
    [[ $k -gt 0 ]] && sleep 300
done
echo "completion status of last rsync is $ss"
```

More recently I have encountered the `retry` command available in (at least) Debian. The loop code can thus be simplified considerably:

```
retry --delay 60 --time 4 rsync …
ss=$?
echo "completion status of last rsync is $ss"
```

Following your question's update, here is the `rsync` command I would use

```
rsync -rtlzq -e "ssh -i c:/RsyncKeys/wa-ecy-gov-test-rsync-key -o ConnectTimeout=140 -o ServerAliveInterval=15" --exclude-from='rsyncfilter.txt' --force --delete --log-file=c:/rsynclogs/rsync11-05-2020.log cran-rsync@cran.r-project.org: //sdceco/Apps/RSTUDIO/RpackagesNew
```

Changes

- Added `ServerAliveInterval=15` for the `ssh` transport to force a disconnect after 45 seconds of no server response whatsoever
- No `-v` (`--verbose`) or `--stats` because you overrode them with `-q` (`--quiet`)
- No `--timeout` because it's managed by `ssh` at the transport level
- The [copying instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/mirror-howto.html) for R warn that `-l` might need to be replaced with `-L` on Windows filesystems. I've not made that change here but you (and future readers) should be aware of it

Comment: I am trying to understand. Are what you are suggesting a 30 second gap between runs of rsync? So if rsync exits with code of 11 then wait 30 seconds before re-running?) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks the problem is with 200k files being copied the error for some other file might occur and also to get to that point again will be much more than 30 seconds potentially. So it seems odds are against me if I always let rsync restart. I hope that makes sense. Again thanks for the replies.

Comment: Thanks roaima I updated my command line as you suggested and I will run it aa few times to see if consistant results occur. Will this have an effect that when a network error occurs it will repeat the file copy where the error occured and move on from there to finish the list? Thanks again Tony.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. If they don't we will need to investigate further as it's then not normal behaviour

Comment: Could also be that the exit code is wrong. It seems to match the code value of 11 and if it does retry and succeed seems like the exit code should be a 0. Anyway, if the problem repeats I will leave the log entry around that code value to get feedback. Again thanks!

Comment: Well the ssh option was not accepted so the script would exit quickly. I have restated the question to get responses from windows users. I am wondering if the windows version I am using does not work like the unix version. Hopefully a windows user can verify my suspicions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well here is an example of the error and what it does on the last try. It never retrys. bin/windows/contrib/3.3/check/bnspatial-check.log
2020/11/10 00:17:51 [6048] rsync: write failed on "//sdceco/Apps/RSTUDIO/RpackagesNew/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/check/bnstruct-check.log": Input/output error (5)
2020/11/10 00:17:51 [6048] rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(374) [receiver=3.1.3]

Comment: Looks like your remote share is failing the write. So `rsync` bails, the `break` doesn't get triggered, so the `sleep` is triggered and the loop recommences for another try. If you keep getting the same error each time around the loop you need to look to fixing the fault on the server hosting `//sdceco/Apps`

Comment: So why would not Rsync keep trying? I expected it would try several times before giving up.

Comment: Why should it? There was a write failure to the target. Fix that and `rsync` will stop aborting. This is not an `rsync` issue, but my suggested code will work around it

Comment: Robocopy detected a problem then waited 30 seconds and  was able to  write the file. That is a standard way to deal with that issue rather than go back over several hundred thousand files and restart. Seems like maybe the RSync maintainers never thought of that? Anyway I was able get that SSH command you suggested. Also, storage systems are known to have read/write issues although you do not hear much about that.so admins usually run some sort of disk checks that mark bad sectors. Not sure what they do with flash drives which also can develop issues after a period of time..

Comment: A storage system that can't handle disk write errors internally is very poor. I think you're confusing disk resilvering here. User level tools should not have to make up for deficiencies in the storage layer. You really need to get your storage layer fixed - it is broken. Just because you are used to it generating io errors doesn't mean it's usual or right

Comment: Although I do not disagree I have discovered over 40 years of development that is usually dependent upon vendor, frequency of updates to evolve a product or service and culture. :-)