# Using retry command with rsync

Tags: rsync

Having problems with the `retry` command when paired with `rsync`.  `retry` is a [Debian package](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/retry/retry.1.en.html) and states it can "Repeat command until a criteria is met, usually success.".  Trying to use it with `rsync` on a connection that can sometimes fail.  However it always gives the same error: `giving up: No such file or directory`:

```bash
retry '/usr/bin/rsync -av source destination'
retry: Could not execute 'rsync -av source destination', giving up: No such file or directory
```

Both `source` and `destination` exist.  I've tried using the absolute path, single and double quotes, quotes around paths, and paths as variables, but none work.  I can use the approach from [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618230/set-retries-on-rsync-to-have-fixed-time-between-them) but it is rather cumbersome when doing several directories.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why not check `$?` within a `while` loop?

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah, that's what [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618230/set-retries-on-rsync-to-have-fixed-time-between-them) solution does.  But if you want a delay after failure and retry count, having `retry` is a lot easier/cleaner--especially if you have several `rsync` commands in a script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see two or maybe three problems here. (And thank you for the link to `retry`; I haven't come across it before.)

1. The target command is parsed "as usual" with spaces between the command and each of its arguments. Quoting the entire command means that `retry` will try and execute that as a command without any parameters:

   ```
   retry 'rsync -av src dst'
   retry: Could not execute 'rsync -av src dst', giving up: No such file or directory
   ```

   The fix here is to avoid quoting the command and its parameters in its entirety.
2. Removing the quotes still generates an error, but this time it's because `retry` is trying to process the `-av` arguments that are intended for `rsync:

   ```
   retry rsync -av src dst
   retry: invalid option -- 'a'
   …
   ```

   The fix here is to use a double dash (`--`) after the parts specific to `retry` so that it stops trying to process further parameters:

   ```
   retry -- rsync -av src dst
   ```
3. Running this to successful completion will result in you ending up with `src` under `dst`:

   ```
   ls dst
   src
   ```

   If you want `dst` to have the contents of `src` then include a trailing slash on `src/`:

   ```
   retry -- rsync -av src/ dst
   ```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `retry` tries to execute a file called `'/usr/bin/rsync -av source destination'` (including the spaces in the middle).

In order to tell `retry` that `rsync` is the command, and `-av` ,`source`, and `destination` are the parameters that belong to the `rsync` command, you'll need to run it the following way:

```
retry -- /usr/bin/rsync -av source destination
```

The reason you'll need the [`--` (double dash)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-does-a-double-dash-in-shell-commands-mean#:%7E:text=A%20double%2Ddash%20is%20a,that%20modify%20behavior%20of%20command.) is to signify the end of command options and beginning of positional arguments. Without the `--` before the command, `retry` will think that `-av` is one of it's command options, and will throw the following error:

```
retry: invalid option -- 'a'
```